# Make a script that pulls information from the current webpage

Tags: vbscript, macros, automation, html, bots

So I am trying to create a script or macro that pulls info from a webpage that I currently have loaded when I press a button or macro on a keyboard. I was looking at vbs but everywhere I look you have to open a new instance of IE or another web browser.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [Help-Center/asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO isn't a script writing service.
To get help you should do a bit more than you expect from others, firstly show the effort you put in your code.

Comment: Post what you have so far... I have a working HTML scraping script but need to see your effort

Answer (score 0):

This lists all shell windows. That is Explorer and Internet Explorer. It contains the IE's window object.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each window in AllWindows
    msgbox window.locationname
    msgbox window.parent
    If window.locationname="Scripts" then window.quit
Next
```

To access the browser like `CreateObject` use `window.parent`.

```
   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

use

```
   Set ie = window.parent
```

To get all text

```
msgbox ie.document.body.innertext
```

This adds a menu item to selected text right click menu to navigate to the selected text (that isn't a link but is a valid URL).

```
<HTML>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="vbscript"> 
set parentwin = external.menuArguments
Set doc = parentwin.document
Set sel = doc.selection
set rng = sel.createRange()
str = lcase(trim(rng.text))

If str="" then
    alert("You must select some text to search for first.")

ElseIf Left(str,7) = "http://" or Left(str,8) = "https://" then
    op = str
Else
    op = "http://" & str
End If

If op <> "" Then open(op)

</SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

To add to menu use this reg file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\&Navigate]
@="C:\\Windows\\WEB\\selnavigate.htm"
"contexts"=hex:10
```

This is from *Internet Explorer 5 Power Toys* © Microsoft. It lists links in a new window. It JScript but VBScript uses the same objects in the same way. http://threeclicks.com/powertoysie5.htm

```
<script language=javascript defer>
var str = new String ("toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=0, left=0, width=400, height=");

str = str + (screen.height - 100);

//alert (screen.height);

var dlProgress = window.open ("", "linkdownloader", str);

dlProgress.document.open();
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<html>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<head>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<title>Links list</title>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</head>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<font style=\"font:   8pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif; line-height:18pt;\">");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("<script language=javascript>function navigateClose(str){if (document.my_parent != null){document.my_parent.location.href=str;window.close();}else{alert(\"Please wait until the list has populated.\");}}<\/script>");

dlProgress.document.writeln ("&nbsp;List of all links in <b>" + external.menuArguments.document.title + "</b>:<ol>");
var links = external.menuArguments.document.links;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    if ( links(i).innerText != "" && links(i).innerText != " ")
    {
        dlProgress.document.writeln ("<li><A HREF='javascript:navigateClose(\"" + links(i).href + "\")' TITLE=" + links(i).href + ">" + links(i).innerText + "</a><BR>");
    }
    else
    {
        dlProgress.document.writeln ("<li><A HREF='javascript:navigateClose(\"" + links(i).href + "\")'>" + links(i).href + "</a><BR>");
    }
}
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</ol><center><a href='javascript:window.close()' style=\"color:#FF0000;text-decoration:none\">close</a></center><BR></body>");
dlProgress.document.writeln ("</font></html>");
dlProgress.document.close();

dlProgress.document.my_parent = external.menuArguments;
</script>
```

Likewise this turn on and off the ability to edit a page.

To put on the tools menu.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{B163952C-2892-4934-AA07-5DEC952BBE3E}]
"CLSID"="{1FBA04EE-3024-11d2-8F1F-0000F87ABD16}"
"Script"="C:\\Windows\\Web\\ViewPage.html"
"MenuText"="Editable Page Off"
"MenuStatusBar"="Turns off page edit mode"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{B749639D-8B7C-4741-87A9-7ABD311F6D72}]
"CLSID"="{1FBA04EE-3024-11d2-8F1F-0000F87ABD16}"
"Script"="C:\\Windows\\Web\\EditPage.html"
"MenuText"="Editable Page On"
"MenuStatusBar"="Turns on page edit mode using standard key and mouse actions"
```

ViewPage.html

```
<script language="VBScript"> 
external.menuArguments.document.body.contenteditable="False" 
</script>
```

EditPage.html

```
<script language="VBScript"> 
external.menuArguments.document.body.contenteditable="True" 
</script>
```